# Wikidump get list of subcategories using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wikipedia

Sorry for my bad English. Please tell me how to get a list of subcategories of category from Wikipedia with three tables: Page, Category, Categorylinks using the mysql query.
I have this code:

```
SELECT `categorylinks`.`cl_to`
FROM `page`
JOIN `categorylinks` ON `categorylinks`.`cl_from` = `page`.`page_id`
WHERE `page`.`page_title` = 'Java'
```

but I think what with this query something wrong...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think something is wring with the query? What does it return and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: This query return 10 rows, when wiki returns 22 subcategories, so I think what there is something wrong, but what I do not understand(

Comment: Look into the database and check all if expected data are inside. Manually through some mysql gui like PHPMyAdmin or something else.